# How to add prefixes to matrix given by a vector?

Tags: r, string, matrix, character

Let's consider matrix:

```
example_matrix <- matrix(c("big", "small", "big_something",
                           "small_really", "small", "big_enough", 
                           "themendous", "big", "small"),ncol = 3, nrow = 3) 

> example_matrix
     [,1]            [,2]           [,3]        
[1,] "big"           "small_really" "themendous"
[2,] "small"         "small"        "big"       
[3,] "big_something" "big_enough"   "small"
```

And some vector:

```
group_vector <- c("group1_big", "group2_small")
```

This vector shows to which words in matrix I should give prefixes `group`. We should end up with:

```
     [,1]            [,2]           [,3]          
[1,] "group1_big"    "small_really" "themendous"  
[2,] "group2_small"  "group2_small" "group1_big"  
[3,] "big_something" "big_enough"   "group2_small"
```

i.e. we replaced every `"big"` in `example_matrix` with `group1_big`, and `"small"` with `"group2_small"` without touching`"big_enough, small_really"` (just replacing exactly `"big"` and `"small"`).

**My Idea**

Let's consider first case i.e. to replace every `"big"` with `"group1_big"`. My idea was to check which elements in `example_matrix` ends with `"big"` and add prefix `"group_1"` for each of them

```
> apply(example_matrix, 2, function(x) endsWith(x, "big"))
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

And my idea how it can be replaced was the following:

```
 apply(example_matrix, 2, function(x) if endsWith(x, "big") paste0(group_vector[1], x) else x)
```

So to put condition - if the specific element really ends on "big" then we add the prefix, if not - we leave it.

This code however produces error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "apply(example_matrix, 2, function(x) if endsWith"
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong and what's the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `str_replace_all` from `stringr` :

```
example_matrix[] <- stringr::str_replace_all(example_matrix, 
                             setNames(group_vector, sprintf('\\b%s\\b', 
                                     sub('group\\d+_', '', group_vector))))

example_matrix
#       [,1]            [,2]           [,3]          
#[1,] "group1_big"    "small_really" "themendous"  
#[2,] "group2_small"  "group2_small" "group1_big"  
#[3,] "big_something" "big_enough"   "group2_small"
```

---

To understand this break it down in smaller steps -

`sub` removes `'group'` + number from `group_vector`.

```
sub('group\\d+_', '', group_vector)
#[1] "big"   "small"
```

We add a word boundary to this so that it only matches the pattern that exactly match (`'big'`) does not match with (`'big_something'`).

```
sprintf('\\b%s\\b', sub('group\\d+_', '', group_vector))
#[1] "\\bbig\\b"   "\\bsmall\\b"
```

Now create a named vector which can be used in `str_replace_all` :

```
setNames(group_vector, sprintf('\\b%s\\b', sub('group\\d+_', '', group_vector)))

#     \\bbig\\b    \\bsmall\\b 
#  "group1_big" "group2_small"
```